# Why is Async feature is not working is chrome.storage callback?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, callback

For the following code, result.arr should be printed first  then result.arr but its the opposite that is happening. How can i prevent this.

```
var ans = null;
async function getUserData() {
  await chrome.storage.local.get(["arr"], function(result) {
      console.log(result.arr);
      ans = result.arr;
    });
  console.log("qr");
}
```

Yes i have gone through those StackOverflow legendary answers about callbacks.

Comment: How is "_result.arr_" opposite to "_result.arr_" ..?

Comment: That's not how callback-based functions should be converted to Promises or async. It's the third time you're asking the same question.

Comment: I suggest using the [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) where you can use the async/await syntax easily, see examples on the linked page.

Comment: Here's an example of the correct conversion: function getUserData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => chrome.storage.local.get("arr", r => resolve(r.arr)));
}

getUserData().then(data => { console.log(data) })